# Twitter style errors for Django TastyPie

Tags: python, django

I need to find a common way to report errors back to my users with [TastyPie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for example looking at twitter this is how they always show errors:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

So errors are an array of errors.

I tried to do something along the same lines in TastyPie like this:

```
def is_valid(self, bundle, request=None):
        errors = {}
        # Check if user already exists before allowing API to create a new one.
        this_email = bundle.data.get('email', None)
        object_count = Member.objects.filter(email=this_email).count()
        if object_count != 0:
            errors['ERRORS'] = 'Duplicate email address'
        return errors
```

But as you can see its not very DRY and the output is not right:

```
{"object_register":{"ERRORS":"Sorry, that page does not exist"}}
```

I have also tried:

```
reply = {}
reply['errors'] = [{'message': 'Sorry we could not log you in.'}]
return self.create_response(request, reply, HttpUnauthorized)
```

So my question is, it is possible to achieve a 'Twitter' style output for errors using Tatypie in a DRY way? If so any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize your error output, you can override `is_valid` method of the resource itself.

```
MyResource(ModelRecource):
    def is_valid(self, bundle):
        errors = self._meta.validation.is_valid(bundle, bundle.request)

        if errors:
            bundle.errors['errors'] = [errors]
            return False

        return True
```